# how to stop scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Hello i have 2 functions , first detect sroll direction up/down , and launch other function (autoscrolling). How to force stop .scroll() function after call ? now it's look's like infinity loop...

```
var pageScroll = function(){

    var iScrollPos = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(e){

        var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {

                App.scrollto((currentPage+1));

            } else {

                App.scrollto((currentPage-1));

            }

        iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;

    });

}
```

and called functions

```
    scrollto: function(page){

        var section_offset = $('section[data-page="'+page+'"]').offset().top;

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: section_offset }, 'slow',function(){

            $('html, body').stop();
            currentPage = page;
            console.log(currentPage);

        });

    }
```

and console log screen http://prntscr.com/4m493q (infinity loop)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.stopScroll = function(){
    this.scroll({top:this.scrollTop+1});
}
```

by done, call whatever element you want, assuming you're scrolling < body >:

```
document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].stopScroll();
```

or with JQuery:

```
$('body')[0].stopScroll();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `$(window).unbind('scroll');`: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score -2):

The parameter you defined as `e` on your scroll callback handler is the `event` object.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
```

Every event on Jquery has a method called `preventDefault()`, that according to the [**Jquery Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

> **Description:** If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

So, calling this method will keep your window of scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try to `return false` at the end of your custom scroll function, or call `preventDefault()` before calling your custom scroll function.